# What's the official library for CSS classes like m-login__title, m-login__form, m-form and m-grid__item?

Tags: css, angular, npm

I am working on an Angular 13 project for a Front End application.

I was asked to add some formatting for one of the screens, with templates like this:

```
<div class="m-login__title">
    ...
</div>
```

And this:

```
<form class="m-login__form m-form" ...>
    ...
</form>
```

I've seen there are lots of projects that use CSS classes like this, but I didn't find a library that teach to use these classes. I've found that Bootstrap and Metronic are possible candidates, but none of them show the usage of CSS classes like these in their examples.

Some Github projects I found use the following paths for their definitions:

```
assets/demo/default/base/scripts.bundle.js
assets/demo/default/base/style.bundle.css
```

But I found the content of these files are radically different between projects.

Where is the official library that supports these classes, and how should I install it?
If possible, I would like to install it via npm.

Comment: This could be just custom css using BEM notation.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @MikeOne. I realized it was a JS/CSS library imported from a vendor that used BEM notation.